# Running htmlunit for .net selenium-webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, htmlunit

Does anyone have any instructions for a .net dev to run HtmlUnit and HtmlUnitDriver as a standalone server so that I can connect to it from .net tests, using selenium-webdriver's RemoteWebDriver?

I'm not interested in porting HtmlUnit, and I'm perfectly happy to run a jar file, I just don't know how to!

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Java installed, it should be as simple as downloading the standalone server jar from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list), then running:

```
java -jar selenium-standalone-server.jar
```

Comment: Excellent! Like the sound of that. Any idea which port I point RemoteWebDriver at?

Comment: Ah. Just ran it, and it tells you - http://127.0.0.1:444/wd/hub. And what's more - there's an overload constructor to RemoteWebDriver that just talks to it. Simply create new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit)